# Changing default menu color for the Galaxy s5

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I want to change the color of the menu(this greenish blue color) the color in the settings menu. I already rooted my device.  Anything will help. Thanks

Comment: You can try Wanam Xposed

Comment: I don't know of any way to change those parts of the UI without rooting and something like Wanam Xposed or a totally different ROM.